# ksh : nohup connects with root user

Tags: solaris, root, ksh, privileges

I'm connected to a Solaris 9 machine using a user1 account.

```
bash-2.05$ /usr/ucb/whoami
user1
```

When i run any command using `nohup`, it executes with `root` privileges:

```
bash-2.05$ nohup whoami &
[1] 20479
bash-2.05$ Sending output to nohup.out
[1]+  Done                    nohup whoami
bash-2.05$ 
bash-2.05$ cat nohup.out   #actually we had to user root here to do `cat` as `nohup.out` belongs to root, but for demonstration i ommited this step
root
```

This behavior can be seen only for this particular account `user1`. For other accounts it's executed with the correct user.

Here's the attributes of nohup

```
bash-2.05$ which nohup
/usr/bin/nohup
bash-2.05$ ls -altr /usr/bin/nohup
-r-sr-xr-x  43 root     bin         5424 Dec  5  2005 /usr/bin/nohup
```

Thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  First, do you login as user1, or as root?  Do a `which nohup` then `ls -l` on the version you are using.  Do you see anything unusual?  Does it have an 's' (set-userid)?

Comment: @cdarke thank you for your reply. I edited the question to a more generic one. There is an 's' there but why when i login with another user i don't see this behavior?

Comment: Not sure, it could be that you might have more than one version of `nohup`, and the other users have a different $PATH.  So far as I know, setting the suid bit (the 's') is unusual, and probably dangerous.  You should ask your system administrator about it.

Comment: @cdarke ok i'll check that. Thank you very much :)